# IPv4 to IPv6 DNS possible?

Tags: networking, dns, proxy, ipv6, 6to4

I setup proxy server [3proxy](https://3proxy.ru/doc/man3/3proxy.cfg.3.html) on my VPS which uses NAT IP4 address but offers IPv6 subnet /64 address I success make  `3proxy` contact outside world using IPv6 ,

But I face other issue many websites didn't have AAAA/IPv6 record at all which was surprise to me , e/g twitter.com can't be resolved . 
So is it possible transfer websites IPv4 address to IPv4 so it will be available to the IPv6 proxy users !
Edit I was able to reach IPv4 site temporary by letting the proxy resolve IPv4 if IPv6 not available `-64` adding this line `3proxy.cfg`.

`proxy -64 -n  -p66505 -a  -i0.0.0.0  -e2a04:f2a7:26:a143:3815:0abf:8723:1000`

Looks like 3proxy tries to resolve host address with Ipv6 if it fails tray with current server IPv4 and bring back data to the proxy client (whether he is connection via IPv4 or IPv6) .
PS After testing IPv6 only connection looks like only Google/YT/facebook and few other website are supporting IPv6 special that have cloudflare the rest of Internet are dark (reddit/twitter/) with no AAAA host record .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but that's not enough. Even if you put an IPv4 address in an AAAA record, IPv6-only clients still will not be able to contact it. (They can't talk using IPv6 packets because the IPv4-only destination won't understand them, and they can't talk using IPv4 packets because the IPv6-only source won't understand them.) So this needs to be paired with packet translation on the router.

Most commonly, you'll see **NAT64** for the packet translation (from v6-only clients to v4-only services), and **DNS64** for the generation of fake AAAA records for those clients. A common NAT64 translator is Tayga (although some ISPs have published their own open-source projects), and several DNS resolvers including Bind9 can do DNS64. Google Public DNS also has special servers which perform DNS64.

But, of course, the NAT64 gateway *itself* must be able to use IPv4. If your current server cannot access the IPv4 Internet, well, that means it cannot.

Comment: No my server can access to IPv4 Internet , but my home connection have only IPv4 , I was thinking using kinda initial tunnel/proxy from my server  IPv4 that masked the main IPv6 proxy which is uses IPv6 only . Last I guess [3proxy](https://3proxy.ru/doc/man3/3proxy.cfg.3.html)  server offer this feature .